# Django Admin view table subsets

Tags: django

I am trying to alter the default django admin pages on my website.
Currently, when I open the admin page I see each of the models I created for my app.

And when I click through these I can also access each row of the tables they relate to. However, I would prefer to view the tables in their entirety, since it's easier to review the data this way.

How can I achieve this? Should I be creating a specific model for this?

Example:
If the database table is in this format:

```
group term 
1     a
1     b 
1     c
2     d
2     e
2     f
```

Currently I can only alter one row at a time
ie.

```
group: 1
term: a
```

But I would rather view the table as it was shown first. Ultimately I would also like to view each group independently - but I am moving one step at a time.

Comment: Can you please be more clear? And, if possible show us your models and your admin model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `list_display` as long as you don't have too many fields

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['group','term']
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks Henry. Is it possible to extend this to the second part of my question? i.e. could I add a layer that I can show subsets of this table by the group column?

Comment: You can add filters, if that is what you mean https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter